# How to send an SMS to trigger AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am trying start a EC2 by sending a text message(Start ec2) from mobile phone.

```
Mobile phone(text message) --> SNS --> Lambda --> EC2
```

I tried Twilio service. But I didn't find any solution.
How I can trigger lambda function from text message. Help me out please. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use a Twilio webhook to post to API Gateway, which then triggers the Lambda.

`Mobile phone (Twilio) ---> API Gateway ---> Lambda ---> EC2`

See https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-node-js for more info on twillio webhooks, and https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/triggering-lambda-functions-via-text-messages/ on a overview of the Twilio-APIGateway-Lambda integration.

Comment: Can I try this in Twilio trial account?

Comment: I didn't see how to send a sms to Twilio which sends to AWS lambda. Can you please explain me clearly.

Answer (score 0):

With AWS Pinpoint you are now also able to receive SMS and trigger a lambda afterwards via SNS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms.html

https://dev.to/imohd23/how-to-trigger-aws-lambda-by-sms-41aj